# 70s(?) movie with abandoned spaceship, onboard computer can answer simple questions, talks about "warning the bridge" when asked elaborate questions

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

I am looking for a movie, problably from the 1970s, where a couple boards a deserted spaceship. When using the onboard computer terminals, the computer answers a few simple questions but on more elaborate questions crashes repeating the phrase "warn the bridge".

I saw this movie when I was a kid but I only caught the first few minutes. It seemed interesting enough (for a 10 year old, that is...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like the TV series "The Starlost" (1973). Look at this interaction with the ship's computer in the pilot episode:

Comment: But the Starlost ship isn't deserted (just mostly uncrewed) and there were three people wandering around.

Comment: It depends on which 'few minutes' were watched. It seems close enough to suggest it.

Comment: Fair enough. Starlost was my first thought too.

Comment: Great SF premise, lousy execution.  I wish someone would dust it off and try again.