# Old movie with abandoned spaceship and skull in helmet

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember a scene from a movie or TV series that I saw in the 80's. It was set on what I think was an abandoned spaceship. An astronaut (main character?) finds a dead crew-member in full space-suit, covered by dust. He (she?) carefully whipes off the dust on visor and reveals the skull of an alien with sharp teeth.

I know this is very thin, but hopefully somebody know what I'm talking about. I've looked through the epguides for the Twilight Zone (1985 version) since i remember following that series, but it doesn't fit any episode. It's very possible the movie was made in the 70's and is more horror than SF.

While looking I came across [Old movie with abandoned spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39378/old-movie-with-abandoned-spaceship) on this site, but it's not The Starlost or any old "tacky" series like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: [This sounds vaguely like this scene in Alien](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-PW2iaXEgrAY/T3RL-RVOtAI/AAAAAAAAAno/U9kfgwsibnQ/s1600/Alien-B48.jpg) Sans visor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Kind of similar, but it's not Alien (or any other "big" scifi movie).

Comment: If you can include any other details, it might help. We are assuming this is live action and in color. Was there anything different about the lighting? Do you remember any details about the ship, suits, chairs, dust? What else do you know it isn't and why?

Comment: Live action and colour, yes - other details no. Sorry, I really can't remember anything except this scene, and hoped someone else would too - but it was a longshot.

Comment: There was a beautiful SF cover of a similar scene (normal teeth though) for the James Hogan novel, *Inherit the Stars*.

Comment: I looking for the same movie.... I find this: azarkant
http://www.kuriositas.com/2013/11/azarkant.html
:-)

Comment: @ganakil: Sound like an interesting movie, but it's a short from 2013 so can't be it. The skull within helmet is a very common trope

Comment: How likely is the 70's time frame?  The 80's was a way more prolific time for outer space horror.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly **Titan Find** AKA **Creature**?

[image]

It is the story of some astronauts who stumble on a creature which can control the dead.

Trailer here:

There is a scene in the trailer which might be the scene you are thinking of - but it is very grainy and hard to tell.

Comment: This looks AWFUL...  I can't wait to watch it!

Answer (score 5):

Although this is a very common depiction in science fiction, here are some suggestions to jog your memory:

Moon Zero Two (1969):

[image]

Star Pilot (1966):

[image]

See [Steve Prideaux](http://sayhellospaceman.blogspot.no/search/label/Skulls%20in%20Space) for more skulls in space.

There's [an illustrated synopsis of "Enemy Mine"](http://rustlemybustle.livejournal.com/91862.html). I've seen the movie and can't recall a skull-helmet scene fitting in anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I think i recognize this scene from the movie Enemy Mine (1985).

Comment: Hmmm... I believe I recall that scene, a Drac skull though wasn't!?